# What is the proper way to use a dependency?

Tags: clojure

Maybe I'm missing something or just reading outdated information.  Basically, I'm trying to use the CSV lib [here](https://github.com/clojure/data.csv/).

I've included it in my project.clj...

```
:dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.3.0"]
               [org.clojure/data.csv "0.1.2"]]
```

...and retrieved the libs successfully using Leiningen.  Now, what would be the proper way to include this lib for use in my program?  I've tried the example posted on the lib's Github page only to get an error stating:

```
FileNotFoundException Could not locate clojure/data/csv__init.class or clojure/data/csv.clj on classpath:   clojure.lang.RT.load (RT.java:430)
```

EDIT: Further clarification on what I've tried: I have the code pasted under my namespace declaration, like so:

```
(ns testprogram.core(:gen-class))
(require '[clojure.data.csv :as csv]
         '[clojure.java.io :as io])
```

Trying it in the REPL yields the same result.  I'm pretty sure I'm trying to 'include' them wrong.

Comment: Please provide additional detail on how you are executing the sample that results in the error. From the REPL (launched from `lein repl`)?

Comment: @noahz Sorry, edited the original post to clarify what I'm trying.

Comment: As long as you are using the namespace macro, you should use the require clauses, i.e. `(ns test.app (:require [clojure.data.csv :as csv] ...` etc. - That said I am getting `Could not find artifact org.clojure/data:csv:jar:0.1.2 in central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2`

Comment: Try `lein classpath` in your project directory and check if the csv library jar is in the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This test worked for me:

```
(ns test.csv-test
  (:gen-class)
  (:require [clojure.data.csv :as csv]
            [clojure.java.io :as io]))

(defn main- [args]
(csv/read-csv "test"))
```

I also encountered the "FileNotFound: could not locate" issue while testing this out. It was a simple typo in my `project.clj` file.  I recommend double-checking that.

Note: this also worked:

```
(require '[clojure.data.csv :as csv]
         '[clojure.java.io :as io])
(defn main- [args]
(csv/read-csv "test"))
```

While using the `:require` directive in the `ns` macro is certainly a best practice, is is not the source of the issue here.

In both versions, REPL output:

```
user=> (in-ns 'test.csv-test)
#<Namespace test.csv-test>
test.csv-test=> (main- [])
(["test"])
```

Also tested with `lein run` and `java -cp <uberjar> test.csv_test`

Comment: Hmm, same error.  Could it have something to do with being on windows?  I mean, I can see the folder containing the CSV lib in my target/classes/clojure/ so I'm pretty sure it's been installed correctly using "lein deps".

What was your typo, by the way?

Comment: `org.clojure/data/csv` instead of `org.clojure/data.csv`

Comment: Ugh, nope.  That's not the issue either.

What's strange is I can compile/uberjar and run the jar without error.  It just keeps giving me that error when reevaluating in Clooj.

Comment: If you can compile / run / run from uberjar, then this seems like an issue with Clooj's environment. You may wish to tweak the question title, content and/or tags to reflect this.

Comment: I seem to be able to parse a CSV as intended when the jar is run, as well.

I think I'll just deal with the error for now and not worry about it as long as it works in the compiled form.

Comment: I've never used Clooj, but reading its documentation it doesn't say anything about libraries on the classpath. You may have to copy the src for data.csv into your Clooj "project" directory.  I recommend using Emacs, Vim (with VimClojure) or IntelliJ IDEA (never used Eclipse, don't know about its Clojure support).

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following: note the :require is nested within the ns declaration. This is the preferred way of doing it.

```
(ns testprogram.core(:gen-class)
(:require [clojure.data.csv :as csv]
          [clojure.java.io :as io]))
```

I think in your case you can get it to work with the following (not tested)

```
(ns testprogram.core(:gen-class))
(require '(clojure.data [csv :as csv])
         '(clojure.java [io :as io]))
```

See the following desc

http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.coreapi.html#clojure.core/require

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. This is not a best practice question, it's a "help fix my error" question.